# Householder QRD on complex matrices w/ the subcondition that the main diagonal of R has only real entires

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

How to adjust the common Householder QRD algorithm so that the main diagonal of the R matrix has only real entries. Right now I use the algorithm described here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0609050.pdf (page 19) to triangulize the matrix. I do not need the Q matrix, it should be used up on the vector that is attached to the matrix. I only need the (triangular) R matrix, with real entries on the main diagonal. Is there a common way to do this? Can this be done by rotating the i-th subrow, A[i][i,i+1,i+2...], (multiplying the subrow with $e^{(-i \theta)} : \theta = arg(A[i,i]))$ in i-th step of the algorithm and multiplying only i-th entry on the attached vector? If not, is there another way to do it? Maybe some literature... Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For any invertible diagonal matrix $D$ you have $A = QR = (QD^{-1})(DR)$. Now, multiplying $D$ from the left to $R$ scales the rows of $R$. So, if you choose $D$ to have the diagonal entries $e^{-i\theta_j}$, then $D$ is unitary and $A = (QD^{-1})(DR)$ remains a $QR$-decomposition of $A$ with $R$ having real diagonal  entries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very helpful.